# Connectify: error during driver install

Tags: networking, connection-sharing, connectify

I had Connectify version 3.7*, than I uninstalled it. Now when I try to install any version of Connectify I get following error:

[image]

After I reboot it shows me this message again or nothing. So connectify is installed only partially and suggests to reinstall when i try to run it (if I choose "reinstall" I see same error message again). I've tried CCleaner - no result.

Comment: Have you tried completely uninstalling it before reinstalling it again? Or perhaps reinstall the version you had, then uninstall it, then install the new(er) version?

Comment: @techie007 Yes, I've tried it - no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connectify 7 installed and running normally

Comment: Please explain. Are you referring to Windows 7?

Comment: I'm on v9.2.2 and this is happening to me. I cannot uninstall it as uninstaller keeps saying there is a reboot pending

Comment: http://support.connectify.me/article/26-connectify-gives-me-a-driver-error-while-installing

Comment: @Hassan 7 is program version

Comment: @janot Please also write how you sorted out the problem.

Comment: @rebel just installed version 7 as already written in my answer

Comment: Not a solution, installing 7 won't fix the installation issues with 9. Probably a workable work-around for almost everybody, but doesn't shed light on the problem or solve it

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall using something like revo uninstaller; (which cleans up left over files and registry entries). Reboot, and try the installation again.

Comment: I have revo uninstaller - no effect

Answer (score 0):

I followed the "install under safe mode" guide and that worked for me finally.

The error of driver installation failure may happen when another application is blocking Connectify Hotspot's driver from installing.

Save the Connectify installer to some place on you computer, and reboot into Safe Mode. Once in safe mode, run the setup and install. Reboot when the setup prompts you to and you'll be back in normal mode. The setup may run again but this time, the drivers would be already there and it will complete successfully.

Here is the official support article: http://support.connectify.me/article/26-connectify-gives-me-a-driver-error-while-installing

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.